# How to build a cluster in order to have full data replication between the nodes?

Tags: cockroachdb

How can i build/configure a cockroach cluster in order to have all data in all nodes? I'm not talking about to have pieces of data spread across the nodes.

I've tried to start a cluster with locality flag but as soon i kill cockroach process in the machine which first recieved the data, i'm no longer able to execute a select and the command only return the data when i start this instance again.

In other words, i wanna to achieve a scenario that if i have total of 3 nodes and i lost 2 of them or they become unavaliabe, i still want to work normally.

In case that cockroachdb does't support this feature. How is the best way to achieve it?

Comment: After some time and whitout flag locality i was able to connect on the second node and retrieve a select from a table with the first node down.However, now i'm trying to select other table with 3 nodes up and no data is been retrieved with select, just a forever waiting with no errors.

Comment: Cockroach console shows 37 replicas in each node. Now, after some minutes a error message came back from that last select: SQL Error [08006]: An I/O error occured while sending to the backend.

Comment: Node 1: Mac os, cockroach 1.5; node 2 and 3: Debian 9, cockroach 1.6 same machine; no container at all

Answer (score 1):

This was answered on our [forum](https://forum.cockroachlabs.com/t/how-to-build-a-cluster-in-order-to-have-full-data-replication-between-the-nodes/1476), but repeating here:

Cockroach requires a majority of replicas to be available for each range to make progress. So, it won't be able to work normally if only 1 of 3 nodes (less than a majority) are available. You can add more nodes to decrease the likelihood of losing a majority.